# How to enable usb debugging

Tags: android

I m using samsung galaxy note gt n7000.. and want to unlock developer option.. because i want to run my eclipse android project in my phone..
i m follwing this steps for unlocking my developer option in my phone..

**

> settings

then

> about phone

then

> build option

then

> tap 7 times

** but unfortunately nothing happens..
then i enable **usb debugging** option from **dveloper option** but still nothing happen..please help

Comment: if developer option is locked, how did you enable usb debugging???

Comment: do you have adb drivers on your computer? 
have you tried other device as well?

Comment: just plug-out the cable and try once again with setting>developer option>on/off and check for adb drivers

Comment: you mean About phone->build number? Try tapping it more

Comment: I found the link
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RDA8PpPSFuk
and it works fine..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you install ADB driver ? in your pc for your device ? Find ADB driver and then enable **Developer Option** and reset ADB from command Prompt as 
adb kill-server
adb start-server

or you can reset adb from DDMS, Devices Pane, Click on Small Don arrow and click **Reset ADB**
Hope it fill solve your problem.